# Ruby on Rails 5.2 active storage resize png loose transparency

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, png

I am using Rails 5.2 
I am trying to resize a png file stored in the active storage as follow

```
def thumbnail
    return self.image_png.variant(resize: '120x120').processed
end
```

The image is then converted to jpg and lose it transparency. Would you know how to keep the image as png with the transparent background?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) to handle variants? It should be RoR default and it is just wrapper for ImageMagick, check what version of ImageMagick you have, for example by running command:

```
convert --version
```

I have locally:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

and I don't have troubles resizing png files and keep transparency.
If you have one of the older versions, try to upgrade ImageMagick first. I have seen problems like this when old version of ImageMagick was used.

Also check how does your record looks in blob table, there is filename field and for some weird reason it must match content type. So make sure that png filename is e.g. `image.png`.

Comment: I had the same problem and checking filename solved it. When filename was without extension, creating smaller variant was making a file without a transparency. When I added ".png" extension it started to work.